# How to setup AWS SNS and SQS for high availability?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

### Problem with SNS

I'm currently using the python [boto3](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) library for SNS (e.g. to create topics, subscribe to topics, send SNS to topics). When I use either a [Resource](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/resources.html) or a [Client](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/clients.html), I have to specify a region (e.g. 'us-west-2', 'us-east-1'). I don't see any built-in options for handling region failover. My question is, how do you setup AWS SNS and SQS for high availability/region failover?

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('sns', region_name='us-west-2')
response = client.create_topic(Name='my_new_topic')
client.subscribe(TopicArn='arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:123456789:some-topic', Protocol='HTTP', Endpoint='Some-HTTP-Endpoint')
```

### Thoughts on Solution for SNS

I was thinking of checking the response of the client. For example, the below is the response of a successful `client.create_topic()`.

```
{'ResponseMetadata': {'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'RequestId': 'adbb58ef-9047-5d44-834d-04a41599eb2b'}, u'TopicArn': 'arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:123456789:some-topic'}
```

If the request didn't succeed, I can retry say X times before attempting a new `region_name`, but this method seems really hacky (since it would always attempt to try the region that's down first and need to keep switching to new clients).

### Problem with SQS

If the above were to succeed (where we can handle SNS across regions), now I have multiple SQS Queues that I would need to read from (again with what seems to be a hacky solution of looping through clients with different regions).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Amazon SNS and SQS are regional services. There is no built-in multi-region availability method for them. If a region fails and you cannot access your topic or queue, you cannot access those same topics/queues by using another region.

There also isn't any standard way to handle them in a multi-region fashion. It really depends on the workings of your application.

One method:

- Writers - Write to one region, if that fails, write to another.
- Readers - Read from multiple queues across multiple regions.

Another method:

- Writers - Write to multiple topics/queues, ensures the message gets somewhere.
- Readers - Read from multiple queues, treat all equally, you will need to manage message duplication.